# Break drop down value into two line but it should be considered as a Single when clicked

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, line-breaks

I have many `<option>`. One of them has a long text and I want to split it into two lines but when I click on that (to get the text via JavaScript) it should act as a single line .

Comment: i want like that Option 7 is on given link : http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find out the solution this code works fine in Firefox :-

```css
 <style>
#wgtmsr{
 width:50px;   
}

#wgtmsr option{
 width:50px;   
}
#wgmstr {
    max-width: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    width: 50px !important;
}
  </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
<option value="value1">value1</option>
<option value="value2">value2</option>
<option value="value3">value3</option>
<option value="value4">value4 ton</option>
<option value="value5">value5</option>
<option id="wgtmsr" value="ounce">Ounce111111111111111111111111111</option>
</select>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

give your li links `display:inline-block` style

```html
 <li><a style="display:inline-block" href="#somewhere">line1<br>line2</a></li>
```

Comment: :- Sir can you please check with below code i want like : http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/2/

Comment: @AnandDwivedi You should edit your question and add that info in. As your question is now, it doesn't have enough information to provide good answers.